# Name of running threads inside a process

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, shell

I have a parent process which creates a thread for each client like this:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, interact, bundle);
```

Then I rename each tread with:

```
pthread_setname_np(thread, "some name");
```

Running command "ps uH p " in my linux terminal, I will get thread details currently running in the parent process, but it doesn't provide the names I just assigned to them.

Is there any specific command to run and get thread names?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html

Comment: @Mat Thanks for your response. unfortunately we cannot use pthread_getname_np in our code and we have to acquire thread names through Linux shell commands.

Comment: Well, read the man page.

Comment: @Mat, I found the example you were referring to. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted at in the `pthread_setname_np`, the new name is accessible as `ps` format specifier `comm`, but not `args` or `command` (which is what is usually printed):

```
ps H -C <cmd name> -o 'pid tid args comm'
```

illustrates the difference (adapted from the `man` page).  I haven't been able to find a good piece of documentation that discusses this explicitly, though.

Here, `<cmd name>` is the name of your program's binary.

Comment: Thanks. So if I replace 'threadname' with my assign name and run the above command, I should get the pid, tid, args, and comm property of my thread?

Comment: Fixed in the above:  it should be the binary's original name.

Comment: I got it working using both you and Mat's instructions. Thanks again